# Text caption constricted to table width

Tags: tables, captions, width

I would like to have my caption text not constricted to the table width, although my doubt is if is it better to have the caption text constricted or not.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Audiencia en papel. Ránking de prensa española. Año: 2011}
\label{tab:aimc}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lrr@{}}\toprule
\bf Medio impreso & \bf Lectores / día*\\
\midrule
 El País & 2.960 \\
 20 Minutos & 2.120 \\
 El Mundo & 1.234 \\
 La Vanguardia & 849 \\
 El Periódico & 731 \\
 ABC & 660 \\
 Público & 299 \\
 La Razón & 298 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end {tabular}\par
\begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item *En miles. Fuente: \cite{AIMC2011}
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for a `threeparttable` here, as you can place the table annotation as part of the `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Audiencia en papel. Ránking de prensa española. Año: 2011}
  \begin{tabular}{ @{} l r r @{} }
    \toprule
    \bfseries Medio impreso & \bfseries Lectores / día* \\
    \midrule
    El País       &   2.960 \\
    20 Minutos    &   2.120 \\
    El Mundo      &   1.234 \\
    La Vanguardia & 849     \\
    El Periódico  & 731     \\
    ABC           & 660     \\
    Público       & 299     \\
    La Razón      & 298     \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \small
    * En miles. Fuente: [1]% \cite{AIMC2011}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Move caption out of `threeparttable`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Audiencia en papel. Ránking de prensa española. Año: 2011}
\label{tab:aimc}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lrr@{}}\toprule
\bf Medio impreso & \bf Lectores / día*\\
\midrule
 El País & 2.960 \\
 20 Minutos & 2.120 \\
 El Mundo & 1.234 \\
 La Vanguardia & 849 \\
 El Periódico & 731 \\
 ABC & 660 \\
 Público & 299 \\
 La Razón & 298 \\
\bottomrule
\end {tabular}\par
\begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item *En miles. Fuente: \cite{AIMC2011}
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a two-line caption, using `\makebox[0pt]` for the second part of the caption text:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array, booktabs,  caption}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\captionsetup{skip=8pt}
\caption{Audiencia en papel. \\\makebox[0pt]{Ránking de prensa española. Año: 2011}}
\label{tab:aimc}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lrr@{}}
\toprule
\bfseries  Medio impreso & \bfseries Lectores / día*\\
\midrule
 El País & 2.960 \\
 20 Minutos & 2.120 \\
 El Mundo & 1.234 \\
 La Vanguardia & 849 \\
 El Periódico & 731 \\
 ABC & 660 \\
 Público & 299 \\
 La Razón & 298 \\
\bottomrule
\end {tabular}\par
\begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item *En miles. Fuente: \cite{AIMC2011}
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]